# Blender quits immediately in background mode

Tags: blender

I would like to run Blender in background mode (without the GUI) in the following manner:

```
blender myscene.blend --background --python myscript.py
```

Immediately after I run the command, Blender quits.
The output from the command shell appears below.
The same happens even if I don't pass the --python myscript.py argument.

What is the problem and how can I make Blender run in background mode?

I'm using Win7 64 bit.

Many thanks,

Igal

The shell output:

```
> "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\blender.exe" -b "C:\Work\data\Synthetic\Test_Scene\Blender\LuxRenderTest.blend" -P "C:\Work\code\Algo\Python\Alfea\alfea\format\blender\render_scene.py"
Read new prefs: C:\Users\igall\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\config\userpref.blend
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\python
[Lux 2018-Jan-18 17:16:31] Attempting to import pylux module from "C:/Users/igall/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/2.78/scripts/addons/luxrender"
[Lux 2018-Jan-18 17:16:31] Pylux module imported successfully
[Lux 2018-Jan-18 17:16:31] Using pylux version 1.6.0  Build 16219
[Lux 2018-Jan-18 17:16:31] Attempting to import pyluxcore module from "C:/Users/igall/AppData/Roaming/Blender Foundation/Blender/2.78/scripts/addons/luxrender"
[Lux 2018-Jan-18 17:16:31] Pyluxcore module imported successfully
[Lux 2018-Jan-18 17:16:31] Using pyluxcore version 1.6
[Lux 2018-Jan-18 17:16:32] Installed scene post-update handler
read blend: C:\Work\data\Synthetic\Test_Scene\Blender\LuxRenderTest.blend

Blender quit
```

Comment: That's the whole point of background mode - open file, perform an action, quit. Are you saying it didn't execute your script? What makes you think so?

Comment: @keltar this was exactly the case. The script was too short and didn't print nothing. When I added a line that prints something to the script, I saw the printout in the plot.